# Assign int to new int

Tags: objective-c, variables, int

So far I have the code

```
- (void)CreatenewBlock:(int)blockCountToSpawn
{
    for (int i=0; i != blockCountToSpawn; i++) 
    {
        theBlockxCord = arc4random() % 4;
        theBlockyCord = arc4random() % 4;
        NSLog(@"New Block with Cords (%i, %i)",theBlockxCord, theBlockyCord);
    }

}
```

This loops until it reaches the anount of blockCountToSpawn
This works exactly how I want it to but I want to set theBlockxCord to a new variable each time. So the end result would be something like:

```
theBlockxCordOfBlock1=2
theBlockxCordOfBlock2=4
theBlockxCordOfBlock3=1
theBlockxCordOfBlock4=3
```

Instead of theBlockXCord being overwritten each time.

For bonus points, Is there a single way to call of them maybe in an array so I don't have to keep doing this:

```
if (theBlockxCordOfBlock1 == 2 || theBlockxCordOfBlock3 == 2 ..etc)
{
   do stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C arrays or an NSMutableArray. You will have to convert the `int`s to `NSNumber`s before you can add it to the array.

```
- (void)CreatenewBlock:(int)blockCountToSpawn
{
    NSMutableArray *blockXCoord = [NSMutableArray array]; // Retain it as needed.
    NSMutableArray *blockYCoord = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i != blockCountToSpawn; i++) 
    {
        [blockXCoord addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % 4)];
        [blockYCoord addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % 4)];
    }

    ...
}
```

if you want to search for `2` then do this

```
if ( [blockXCoord indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]] != NSNotFound ) {
    ... do stuff
}
```

or

```
if ( [blockXCoord containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]] ) {
    ... do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

```
for ( int i = 0; i < [blockXCoord count]; i++ ) {
    NSPoint point = NSMakePoint([[blockXCoord objectAtIndex:i] intValue],[[blockYCoord objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);

    ... do something with the point.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus but the original question is still dwindling.

Comment: I didn't get you. Replace the current assignment with this one and it should work, right?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused of [blockXCoord addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % 4)]; Where is the array it's adding to?

Comment: indexOfObject: will certainly work, but I think containsObject: is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks! What if I want to compare everything in the array to a single int such as: if ([blockXCoord indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:all]] != playerxcord)

Comment: @evdude100 2 is the int you are searching for. Anyways, like @Trott said, it looks like `containsObject` is a better method to use and understand.

Comment: That was actually an example.. I actually want to compare everything in the BlockXCords array to an int declared else where in my program like xcord.

Comment: @Deepak could I say containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:PlayerXCord]

Comment: yeah that would be the idea. And if you are using the array elsewhere, you will probably want to declare it as an ivar.

Comment: I'm going to test in a moment then elect your answer as the solution, because I can use it to leverage any noobish bothersome questions after I test it that I might have lingering :-)

Comment: @Deepak Probably my last one, If there a way to create an NSPoint with values from the array? I want to basically draw a black square at every coordinate of the array

Comment: If you wish you can store the points in array too. `NSPointMake(x,y)` for the point and `[NSValue valueWithPoint:aPoint]` will give you an `NSValue` object that can be stored in the array.

Comment: Actually I want to achieve just the opposite something along the lines of: NSPoint center = {blockYCord,blockXCord};

Comment: Edited the answer to include the conversion back to `NSPoint`.

Comment: Thanks for this but I get the error: Semantic Issue: Passing 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') after using the Point for drawing?

Comment: yeah, my mistake. I didn't convert it back to `int`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question:  Put your results in either a conventional array just like any C program or in an NSMutableArray. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

For your second question: If you used an NSMutableArray to store objects (say, an NSNumber), you can call `containsObject:` to determine if an object is in the array.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:

Comment: containsObject sounds great! Thanks :-)